# in java,how to iterate list of objects

Tags: java, iteration

i am having the list `myEmpls`

```
List myEmpls = new ArrayList();
```

In this list i have added used defined objects.

```
LogConf e = getLogs(el);
    //add it to list
 myEmpls.add(e);
```

Now how to iterate the list of objects and get the values from this objects.
How to do this?

Answer (score 17):

You could just google this and you would find tons of solutions.. But here is the code:

```
for(LogConf element : myEmpls) {
  System.out.println(element.getValue());
}
```

You should also get used to define the type of the elements in the list:

```
List<LogConf> myEmpls = new ArrayList<LogConf>();
```

Answer (score 3):

I know its been some time since this post was made. You can also use the Iterator.

```
              List myEmpls = new ArrayList();
              Iterator itr = myEmpls.iterator();

              while(itr.hasNext()) {   
                   LogConf Logobj = (LogConf) itr.next();
                   System.out.println(Logobj.getterName());
              }
```

Hope this helps someone.