# Java ArrayList<>() Fetch

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, object-oriented-database

I have FilmDAO which have List  getAllFilm(), in the main i have :

```
List <Film> lsfilm = new ArrayList <Film>();
lsfilm = FilmDAO.getAllFilm();
```

My question is how to fetch the list objects one by one, and get only the name of the movie (nomFilm) so i can add it in the Choice list (ComboBox).

Comment: what is meant with  new ArrayList <Film>[]; did your code compiled even?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in java,how to iterate list of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007429/in-java-how-to-iterate-list-of-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somthing like this :)

```
 if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(lsfilm)){
    for (Film film : lsfilm){
       comboBox.add(film.getNameFilm());
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a for-each loop to add the film names to your ComboBox.

```
for (Film f : lsfilm){
   String filmName = f.nomFilm;
   myComboBox.addItem(filmName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dansienmens it should work now with turning only names into an array.